# How to import local CSV via cypher-shell+bolt from my computer on a server?

Tags: neo4j, cypher-shell

I need to import CSV from a local folder (on my computer) on a server.

First I start the cypher-shell:

`cypher-shell.bat -a bolt://<address>:7687 -u user -p secret`

That works (I can do any Cypher-operation I want to do).

After that I try to load the data from my local neo4j-installation:
`USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM 'C:/Users/.../neo4j-community-3.5.6/import/file.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
CREATE (:Term { name: line[1], description: line[2]});`

I get an error: "unknown protocol: c". So I think, the declaration of the local path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend `file:///` in the file path to specify when loading from the local file system.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///C:/Users/.../neo4j-community-3.5.6/import/file.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
CREATE (:Term { name: line[1], description: line[2]});
```

By default, the neo4j import directory is set to $NEO4J_HOME/import.
You need to comment following line in the neo4j.conf file:

```
dbms.directories.import=import
```

Comment: Ok, but now I get: "Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/usr/people/neo4j/run/.../import/C:/Users/.../neo4j-community-3.5.6/import/file.csv". I think "C:/.../file.csv" is interpreted as a file inside the import-folder on the the server.

Comment: added more details

Comment: Thx for information. I just started a test regarding the further information (-> config-file). I get the same error, but the displayed path inside the error message is correct now. I also tested the path itself on my local computer to make sure that it is correct. It's ok. Maybe, there is a problem with access rights (windows 7)?